# Running into error while using selenium python? Any suggestions

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm still learning and im trying to automate something. I am trying to execute the below code. I tried to run the code, but it still does not work.

Input:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
   
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/deep/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver') 
url = 'https://healthscreening.schools.nyc/?type=G'

driver.get(url)

last_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="guest_last_name"]').send_keys('test test')
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="guest_email"]').send_keys('testtest@gmail.com')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnDailyScreeningSubmit"]/button').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('')

driver.quit
```

Output:

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error:
```

Any suggestions on what to do? On macos using vscode

Comment: where is url defined ?

Comment: just edited, was cleaning up the code and accidentally cut it out

Comment: oh ok .. can u try with full xpath ? and also its not driver.quit .. its driver.quit() . [calling quit function .. ]

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: what is this --> `driver.find_element_by_xpath('')`

Comment: `element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'your xpath')` can you try this ?

Comment: 2 things need to update: 1.  quit is a method so you need to update it like: driver.quit() 2. driver.find_element_by_xpath('') this line is for no use, remove it. After this, this code is running fine in windows 10 in pycharm.